# Task.Factory.StartNew() Delay Under Mono / MonoTouch

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios

Under Mono and MonoTouch, I am seeing an approx 500 millisecond delay between when I call:

```
StartNew(Action<object> action, object state, CancellationToken cancellationToken, 
    TaskCreationOptions creationOptions, TaskScheduler scheduler);
```

and when the worker code actually starts executing.

I created a test to show this:

```
public static class TestTaskFactory
{
    private class TaskInfo
    {
        public int Number;
    }

    private static int NUM_TASKS = 5;
    private static int NumFinished = 0;

    public static void Run()
    {
        for (int n = 1; n <= NUM_TASKS; n++)
        {
            Log("Starting task #" + n + " ...");
            var task_info = new TaskInfo { Number = n };
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker, task_info, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }

        Log("Waiting for tasks to finish ...");
        while (NumFinished < NUM_TASKS)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }

        Log("All done");
    }

    private static void Worker(object state)
    {
        var task_info = (TaskInfo)state;
        Log("Task #" + task_info.Number + " running");

        // Do something
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        // Done
        ++NumFinished;
    }

    private static void Log(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH.mm.ss.fff") + ": Thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + ": " + msg);
    }
}
```

Output under Mono on Mac:

```
16.57.31.420: Thread 1: Starting task #1 ...
16.57.31.508: Thread 1: Starting task #2 ...
16.57.31.508: Thread 1: Starting task #3 ...
16.57.31.508: Thread 1: Starting task #4 ...
16.57.31.508: Thread 1: Starting task #5 ...
16.57.31.508: Thread 1: Waiting for tasks to finish ...
16.57.31.510: Thread 5: Task #1 running
16.57.32.009: Thread 6: Task #2 running <-- Approx 500 msec later
16.57.32.511: Thread 7: Task #3 running <-- Approx 500 msec later
16.57.33.012: Thread 8: Task #4 running <-- Approx 500 msec later
16.57.33.513: Thread 9: Task #5 running <-- Approx 500 msec later
16.57.35.515: Thread 1: All done
```

It is as if Mono wants to wait up to 500 msec to reuse an existing thread before spawing a new one. If I decrease the worker time below 500 msec, the delay decreases. For example, changing the worker Thread.Sleep(2000) to Thread.Sleep(50):

```
...
17.13.20.262: Thread 5: Task #1 running
17.13.20.314: Thread 5: Task #2 running <-- approx 50 msec later
17.13.20.365: Thread 5: Task #3 running <-- approx 50 msec later
17.13.20.416: Thread 5: Task #4 running <-- approx 50 msec later
17.13.20.466: Thread 5: Task #5 running <-- approx 50 msec later
```

But under MS Framework 4.0, no **large** delay before worker code starts:

```
...
17.05.42.238: Thread 9: Waiting for tasks to finish ...
17.05.42.256: Thread 11: Task #1 running
17.05.42.256: Thread 12: Task #3 running <-- little delay
17.05.42.256: Thread 13: Task #4 running <-- little delay
17.05.42.257: Thread 10: Task #2 running <-- little delay
17.05.43.264: Thread 14: Task #5 running <-- little delay
```

Before I submit a bug report on Mono, I wanted to sanity check that I am not missing some tweak I need to make on Mono or using Task.Factory wrong. I am actually using a max concurrency scheduler in my real app.

So my question: is this a bug in Mono/MonoTouch?

Update: I've switched from using ThreadPool under Mono* to Ami Bar's Smart Thread Pool ([github](https://github.com/amibar/SmartThreadPool); [Code Project article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool)). GSerjo's [Extended Thread Pool](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27358/Extended-Thread-Pool) also looked nice, but had alot of dependencies that I was trying to avoid on mobile. I wrote up some of my simple testing at a [Xamarim thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/289/threadpool-thread-creation-throttling). I probably missed 100 other thread pool implementations, but I've been happy with SmartThreadPool so far. Use  WINDOWS_PHONE mode to compile under MonoTouch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So my question: is this a bug in Mono/MonoTouch?

Not necessarily. I suspect it's just the thread pool being unwilling to start more than one new thread every 500ms. Note that you're seeing the *first* task start up pretty much instantly. It's only after that that you're seeing a delay.

If you use more tasks on .NET 4.5, you'll see something similar, except with "chunks" of threads starting each second.

You may find that calling [`ThreadPool.SetMinThreads`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads.aspx) helps, assuming that's available in MonoTouch.

Comment: Yes, SetMinThreads() did the trick. The 500 msec value seems very arbitrary. That is a super long time even under iOS let alone Mono for Mac where I also see this. Based on quick googling this may be a constant from a certain version of MS Framework. I will research/experiment more and report back. Mono defaults do not feel right to me.

Comment: @t9mike: Yes, I think that was the timing before .NET 4, where the thread-pool was rewritten pretty much completely, I believe.

Comment: The slow start for threads in the threadpool is there to avoid a thread storm.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to definition of "thread storm" @miguel.de.icaza? I came up empty googling.

Comment: He's probably talking about starting threads too quickly, when existing threads are already about to finish.  Having more than one thread per CPU core is expensive, you'll pay a performance penalty anyways due to increased context switches.  AFAIK, the .NET 3.5 CLR even uses a logarithmic slowdown each time you cross that # threads per CPU mark.

Comment: So basically on a 8 core CPU, your first 8 threads are cheap, then thread #9 would require context switches, so if one of the first 8 threads quickly becomes available, it's more efficient to wait for it.  Same things then happens again for thread #17, #25, etc.

Comment: Thanks Martin. My issue is that max 500 msec thread spinup time seems awfully long. It is fixed on Mono AFAICT and not platform dependent. My fear is someone using ThreadPool to launch tasks that are not super short lived with see this and cause poor startup performance. I have switched to using https://github.com/amibar/SmartThreadPool and am very happy with it so far.

Comment: This is even a bigger issue for C#5 and async/await and Tasks... Using a load of Tasks trashes the ThreadPool.

Comment: @jduncanator: In what way? Tasks are designed to be lightweight, such that it's fine to queue many, many tasks. Also note that the tasks created by async/await typically aren't tasks started in the threadpool anyway.

Comment: You can also define an environment variable, `MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU`, to set the amount of threads per CPU it will allow before imposing a penalty

Comment: @JonSkeet `Task.Delay` under both .NET and Mono uses a `System.Threading.Timer` under the hood to trigger the callback. Also, in some situations where you use Async/Await as a shortcut to an event based asynchronous design, and you use await and Tasks a lot for really short running operations it has to start a new Thread for each Task, something that happens a lot for us in our Game server.

Comment: We saw serious latency issues in our game server when switching to Mono until we upped the MinThreads or we set MONO_THREADS_PER_CPU to something higher. Then all latency issues went away!

Comment: @jduncanator: This is the first mention of `Task.Delay` in the whole question and answer... I don't see how that is relevant here. And no, it *doesn't* have to start a new thread for each task - that's entirely untrue, at least in the normal .NET framework (and I'd hope it's untrue in Mono as well). One of the *purposes* of tasks is to avoid having to create a new thread for each of them. (Look at the diagnostics in the question, which clearly shows several tasks using the same thread.)

Comment: @jduncanator: Basically, it sounds like you should start a new question with your situation - it doesn't sound particularly relevant to this question, which is about how the thread pool delays creating new threads just to start with.

Comment: It wasn't a question, it was more of a comment. Your answer says to increase MinThreads, I was providing an alternative to hardcoding it into a program by simply setting an environment variable, thats all. Looking at the diagnostics in the question just proves what I was saying, each task is executing under a new thread (when it is working properly)

Comment: @jduncanator: Only for a small number of threads. If they're shortlived tasks, the whole point of the thread pool is that the threads are reused. Your claim that "it has to start a new Thread for each task" is simply untrue. async/await itself doesn't start *any* new threads - it entirely depends on what you're awaiting, and what the scheduler does.