# Newly created threads using Task.Factory.StartNew starts very slowly

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

In an WPF/c# application that uses around 50-200 of short living worker-threads created by `Task.Factory.StartNew` it takes from 1 to 10 seconds before the newly created thread starts executing.

What is the reason for this very slow thread execution start?

**Update:**
The delay is excatly 500 msec

Comment: It will just use a `ThreadPool` thread, of which there is a limited pool available. You may be experiencing thread starvation.

Comment: That depends upon so many factors. Your system logical processor count, system resource availability, process priority, thread priority, ThreadPool min max threads limit, Your process's threadpool threads activity during that time, etc

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - but dosen't Task.Factory.StartNew uses the ThreadPool? A Task used in Task.Factory.StartNew uses a TheadPool thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen Yes it does, of which there are only a limited number. If the `ThreadPool` is fully allocated, it either costs time to wait or costs time to create new threads.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads returns 1023 / 1000

Comment: @MortenFrederiksen Can you provide a sample that demonstrates the problem? Just trying to increase the tempo of the question and give potential answerers something to experiment against.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found out that the thread pool can be unwilling to start more than one new thread every 500 msec when the number of thread pool threads used are over a specific value. However increasing MinThreads using [ThreadPool.SetMinThreads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) - even though it is not recommended - to 100 enables me to create 100 threads without the 500 msec delay.

Here's what helped me:

- http://alexpinsker.blogspot.com/2009/06/threadpool.html
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/13186389/600559

**Edit:**

Here's what I ended doing in `App.xaml.cs` (in the constructor):

```
// Get thread pool information
int workerThreadsMin, completionPortThreadsMin;
ThreadPool.GetMinThreads(out workerThreadsMin, out completionPortThreadsMin);
int workerThreadsMax, completionPortThreadsMax;
ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads(out workerThreadsMax, out completionPortThreadsMax);

// Adjust min threads
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(workerThreadsMax, completionPortThreadsMin);
```